# Copy Column ranges into a single series in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have data ranges that span couple of columns `(C:D)`, `(M:N)` and `(Q:R)`. I am trying to copy the first row in each of the series and paste it to another sheet. As in combine the ranges into a single range with the following sequence

The sequence of copy and pasting I am trying to do is

1. First row of range `(C:D)`
2. First row of range `(M:N)`
3. First row of range `(Q:R)`
4. Second row of range `(C:D)`
5. Second row of range `(M:N)`
6. Second row of range `(Q:R)`

and then the Third row and so on.. I am trying to paste the ranges into another sheet.

So far I have done this by copying each row at a time and pasting one after another. But I am finding it difficult to convert this into a loop which will copy and paste any number of rows to another sheet.

```
Sub CopyCol()

Sheets("Sheet10").Range("C2:D2").Copy
Sheets("Sheet11").Range("B2:C2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("Sheet10").Range("M2:N2").Copy
Sheets("Sheet11").Range("B3:C3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("Sheet10").Range("Q2:R2").Copy
Sheets("Sheet11").Range("B4:C4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("Sheet10").Range("C3:D3").Copy
Sheets("Sheet11").Range("B5:C5").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("Sheet10").Range("M3:N3").Copy
Sheets("Sheet11").Range("B6:C6").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Sheets("Sheet10").Range("Q3:R3").Copy
Sheets("Sheet11").Range("B7:C7").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

...
End Sub
```

The copy and paste does not stop there it goes on. I have just pasted a snippet of the code. The number of rows in each of the series is 45.

Is there a way to reduce the number of lines? I could not figure out how to do it using a loop.

Any help or any suggestions would be really helpful and really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the following code - here's the points to take note of:

- you can create the sheet and range references (`wsSource`, `rngSource`, etc) and this prevents you needing to constantly refer to `Sheets("Sheet10")` or `Range("C2:D2")` etc - this is also a good practice.
- you can use other variables to define your range variables - the code below has two counters - one for the 45 rows of source data and one to track the target row in the other sheet
- you need to loop through the source data, but you don't loop through  the target data as you are appending to the same columns `B:C` and therefore just need a row counter tracking your position in the target sheet

HTH

```
Sub CopyCol()

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsTarget As Worksheet

    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rngTarget As Range

    Dim intSourceRowCounter As Integer
    Dim intTargetRowCounter As Integer

    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet10")
    Set wsTarget = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet11")

    intTargetRowCounter = 1
    For intSourceRowCounter = 1 To 45
        Set rngSource = wsSource.Range("C" & intSourceRowCounter & ":" & "D" & intSourceRowCounter)
        Set rngTarget = wsTarget.Range("B" & intTargetRowCounter & ":" & "C" & intTargetRowCounter)
        rngTarget.Value = rngSource.Value
        intTargetRowCounter = intTargetRowCounter + 1

        Set rngSource = wsSource.Range("M" & intSourceRowCounter & ":" & "N" & intSourceRowCounter)
        Set rngTarget = wsTarget.Range("B" & intTargetRowCounter & ":" & "C" & intTargetRowCounter)
        rngTarget.Value = rngSource.Value
        intTargetRowCounter = intTargetRowCounter + 1

        Set rngSource = wsSource.Range("Q" & intSourceRowCounter & ":" & "R" & intSourceRowCounter)
        Set rngTarget = wsTarget.Range("B" & intTargetRowCounter & ":" & "C" & intTargetRowCounter)
        rngTarget.Value = rngSource.Value
        intTargetRowCounter = intTargetRowCounter + 1

    Next intSourceRowCounter

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, learnt a new thing today and was really helpful :)